# Undefined reference to select@20 in C

Tags: c, input, linker-errors

I'm trying to give the user a certain period of time to enter the move and I found a tutorial featuring `fflush()` and `select()`, however, there's an error:

> undefined reference to select@20

A stripped version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main() {
    struct timeval tmo;
    fd_set readfds;

    for (int x = 0;;x++) {
        do {
        printf("\nEnter a move: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        /* wait only 5 seconds for user input */
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(0, &readfds);
        tmo.tv_sec = 5;
        tmo.tv_usec = 0;

        switch (select(1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tmo)) {
        case -1:
            err(1, "select");
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("User didn't give an input.");
            return (1);
        }

        scanf(" %c", &userInput);
        translateUserInput(userInput, &dx, &dy);
        }
        while (!isDirectionOk(field, snake, dx, dy));
    }
}
```

I'm on Windows by the way.

Comment: One of  `#include <unistd.h>` or `#include <windows.h>` should be generating an error.  Which compiler/version are you using?

Comment: It's a preinstalled compiler by CodeBlocks. I looked into the installation folder and found this TDM-GCC Compiler Suite for Windows  GCC 5 Series  MinGW 32-bit Edition. Is this it?

Comment: It's a linker problem you probably need to link with `Ws2_32.lib`.

Comment: Solved. (For anyone using MinGW, the Ws2_32.lib is called libwsock32.a here, specifically for Code Blocks users, you need to go to Project -> Build Options -> add ->libwsock32.a)

Comment: So please write an answer and mark it. That's the way SO works, also for self-answered questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link `Ws2_32.lib`.

If you're using MinGW, the library is called `libwsock32.a`.

For anyone using Code::Blocks, go to Project -> Build Options -> Linker Settings -> Add -> libwsock32.a.

[image]